# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA vs ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE, what is the difference?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.6

What is the functional difference between these two commands?

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM old_role;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE old_role IN SCHEMA schema_name 
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS FROM old_role
```

Do they achieve the same thing, or is each one specifically doing something different? If so, what?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) that seems unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) says:

> If `FOR ROLE` is omitted, the current role is assumed.

So the first statement affects default privileges on objects created by the user that ran the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement, while the second statement affects default privileges on objects created by `old_role`.

The first statement will undo default privileges previously granted with

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name 
   GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO old_role;
```

while the second statement will undo privileges granted with

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE old_role IN SCHEMA schema_name 
   GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO old_role;
```

Note that both statements will do nothing unless such privileges have previously been granted:

> Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever the global default privileges are for the particular object type. This means you cannot revoke privileges per-schema if they are granted globally (either by default, or according to a previous `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command that did not specify a schema). Per-schema `REVOKE` is only useful to reverse the effects of a previous per-schema `GRANT`.

Comment: Now it is clear to me. Thank you very much.